# Italic to some fonts not getting applied in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, fonts, truetype

I am trying to apply font style italic to the following fonts in wpf

Arial Narrow
Calibri Light,
Franklin Gothic Demi ,
Franklin Gothic Heavy,
Franklin Gothic Medium.,

But italic is not coming. Please note that these fonts  have installed italic installed in the system.

I feel this is a wpf related bug. So if anyone have faced the issue please let me know of fix, workaround etc

xaml code

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontSize="40" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Normal">
   Text
</TextBlock>
```

In the main code I will list all the installed font families and i have buttons for applying bold and italic styles. All other fonts except those listed above are working fine.

Comment: Can you provide a code (xaml) sample relevant to what you are asking?

Comment: I have edited the question with xaml sample

Comment: Not all fonts support italic.  Arial Narrow will not Italic on my system but Arial will.

Comment: Arial Narrow has italic font(this can be confirmed by searching font directory and using applications like word). So italic should be supported

Comment: @Paparazzi That is exactly the issue I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fonts you've referring to, are not font families in WPF font selection model, but selected from base font family based on FontStyle, FontWeight and FontStretch properties.

That means that to get Arial Narrow, it's better to specify FontFamily="Arial" and FontStretch="Condensed", not FontFamily="Arial Narrow". (it would also work with FontFamily="Arial Narrow", but other properties will not work).

Examples:
This will be Arial Narrow

```
<TextBlock Text="Test Arial Narrow" FontFamily="Arial" FontStretch="Condensed"/>
```

Arial Narrow Italic

```
<TextBlock Text="Test Arial Narrow" FontFamily="Arial" FontStretch="Condensed" FontStyle="Italic"/>
```

Arial Narrow Bold

```
<TextBlock Text="Test Arial Narrow" FontFamily="Arial" FontStretch="Condensed" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Arial Narrow Italic Bold

```
<TextBlock Text="Test Arial Narrow" FontFamily="Arial" FontStretch="Condensed" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

This will NOT work as expected (will not be Italic):

```
<TextBlock Text="Test Arial Narrow" FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontStyle="Italic"/>
```